# what are the commands that can work in vi and not in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Vim is an ascendant text editor to vi and is 99% compatible to the latter can someone tell me what is the 1%. I mean the command that can be executed in vi mode and not in vim.

Comment: Where did you get that 99%?

Comment: `Although Vim is 99% Vi compatible `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the list at `:help vi-differences`. The only noted omission from Vim is the *open mode*; in Vim, `:open` is only emulated.

The runtime behavior can be controlled via the `'cpoptions'` option; each letter in it stands for one vi-compatibility; most are turned off in Vim-mode (i.e. with `:set nocompatible`, or when a `.vimrc` file is found).